# Modifying and setting PATH within a .bat script (Windows)

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, path

I got sick of modifying my path to swap around between java6/7/8 and decided to make a quick little .bat script to do it for me.

A previous iteration of this was working on my last laptop, but on my new one neither the last iteration nor this one seems to work.

What I'm trying to do is grab my PATH variable, swap out the string "jdk#" with whatever other "jdk#" I'm intending to use. The setting of JAVA_HOME appears to be executing fine and the whole script executes without errors, but it seems the string replacement isn't happening and I'm not sure why.

```
@echo off

@REM Cycle through all the arguments passed in
for %%x in (%*) do (

    @REM if the current argument is "mvn" switch the versions
    IF "%%x"=="mvn" (
        @REM Temporarily move to the Maven 2 directory
        PUSHD C:\PROGRA~1\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin\
        @REM if the RENAME file exists then Maven 3 was enabled and we need to rename it
        IF EXIST "mvnRENAME.bat" (
            REN "mvnRENAME.bat" "mvn.bat"
            ECHO Maven 2 enabled
        ) ELSE (
            @REM otherwise we need to hide the mvn.bat file to enable Maven 3
            REN "mvn.bat" "mvnRENAME.bat"
            ECHO Maven 3 enabled
        )
        @REM Return back to the original directory
        POPD
    )

    @REM Swap to java 6
    IF "%%x"=="java6" (
        ECHO Java 6 enabled

        @REM Replace instances of jdk7 with jdk6
        set "PATH=%PATH:jdk7=jdk6%"
        setx -m PATH "%PATH:jdk7=jdk6%"

        echo.%PATH%

        @REM Replace instances of jdk8 with jdk6
        set "PATH=%PATH:jdk8=jdk6%"
        setx -m PATH "%PATH:jdk8=jdk6%"

        echo.%PATH%

        @REM Set java home
        set "JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk6\"
        setx -m JAVA_HOME C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk6\
    )
)
```

Running this script doesn't seem to modify my path at all, as the path still contains "C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk7\bin" afterwards.

Am I misunderstanding how the string:find=replace function works? Is my syntax off? Any help would be appreciated.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Added SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION and then did this bit below.

```
set pathtext=!PATH:jdk7=jdk6!
echo.!pathtext!

set "!PATH!=!pathtext!"
setx -m !PATH! "!pathtext!"
```

The variable pathtext now contains what I want my path to be (both in the current command line and permanently in the system) but the set and setx methods aren't doing what I'm expecting. I assume I'm misunderstanding how to use the ! operators in here.

Comment: `%%x` is a for variable only valid in the scope of the for statement or (code block). And setting a variable inside a code block requires delayed expansion to be set with setlocal and the use of `!` instead of `%` signs to enclose the variable name when using it inside the very same code block.

Comment: The %%x is fine, that's not being used anywhere aside from the if statement and is working as intended. I'm still not quite sure I follow on the second part. Since I'm attempting to modify a system variable (both locally and actually setting it for the system) how would that work with delayed expansion turned on?

Comment: I'll edit it to include the entire swap script. I'm using a for loop to go through all of the command line args passed in, and that part is working correctly. It's just the find/replace that doesn't seem to be working, since the set works for JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Move the `echo` of the modified `path` outside of the parenthisised block. See `delayed expansion` (many SO items) for explanation.

Comment: Either use [SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) or change the `Echo %Path%` to `Call Echo %%Path%%` to use a different method of forcing expansion to the current values.

Comment: So I added SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION to the top and experimented with the code block I added. The chunk partially does what I expect. pathtext now contains what I want, but it isn't setting them how I expect it to.

Comment: `set "!PATH!=!pathtext!"` attempts to set a variable named (the contents of `path`) to the value (the contents of `pathtext`). Remove the exclamation marks from `path` (ditto for the `setx` command)

Comment: I'm going to post the entire thing over where the small block was. My chunk now correctly globally sets the environment variables but doesn't locally change them.

Comment: Well maybe never mind. Now I'm getting "setx is not recognized as an internal or external command" so I borked up my path along the way somewhere. I think your last comment got me where I needed to go though, thank you.

Comment: [`PATHEXT`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) is also a system-reserved variable name just like `PATH`, so you should use another interim variable name...

Comment: Yeaaaaah, just noticed that as I scrolled down a bit further. Face -> Palm.